# How to add column name as header when using dataflow to export data to csv

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am exporting some data to csv by Dataflow, but beyond data I want to add each column names as the first line on the output file such as

```
    col_name1, col_name2, col_name3, col_name4 ...
    data1.1, data1.2, data1.3, data1.4 ...
    data2.1 ...
```

Is there anyway to do with current API?(searched around `TextIO.Write` but didn't find anything seems relevant...) or is there anyway I could sort of "insert" column name at the head of to-be-exported PCollection and enforce the the data to be written in order...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Dataflow SDK version 1.7.0, you have [withHeader](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/TextIO.Write#withHeader-java.lang.String-) function in [TextIO.Write](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/TextIO.Write) .

So you can do this:

```
TextIO.Write.named("WriteToText")
            .to("/path/to/the/file")
            .withHeader("col_name1,col_name2,col_name3,col_name4")
            .withSuffix(".csv"));
```

A new line character is automatically added to the end of the header.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to do that using `TextIO.Write`. `PCollection`s are unordered so it isn't possible ot add an eleemnt to the front. You could write a custom [`BoundedSink`](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/custom-io#creating-sinks) which does this.

Comment: Thank you ben, ahh i have a follow up question... is there any way I could define different behavior for different shard, say I have final output write to n shards csv file, but I just want to write header to only one shard...

Answer (score 1):

[Custom sink APIs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/custom-io#creating-sinks) are now available if you want to be the brave one to craft a CSV sink. Current workaround which builds up the output as a single string and outputs it all at finish bundle:

```
PCollection<String> output = data.apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 0;

String new_line = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String csv_header = "id, stuff1, stuff2, stuff3" + new_line;
StringBuilder csv_body = new StringBuilder().append(csv_header);

@Override
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
    csv_body.append(c.element()).append(newline);
}

@Override
public void finishBundle(Context c) throws Exception {
    c.output(csv_body);
}

})).apply(TextIO.Write.named("WriteData").to(options.getOutput()));
```

This will only work if your BIG output string fits in memory